GeoServer Error: Unknown WKB type: 242
I am using GeoServer 2.23 and visualizing data from PostgreSQL.
One of the layers shows an rendering error. Not in general for the whole layer, but only in some areas:
org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: An exception occurred while parsing WKB data
An exception occurred while parsing WKB data
Unknown WKB type 242

As a result, some polygons are missing in the WMS. But all polygons are present in the database.
As I researched on the Internet, there are only 24 types of WKB:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry
What can I do to fix this?

What type is your geometry column? And what does GeoServer think it is?

Geometry column: srid 4326. GeoServer defines the same. Unusual is that layer is working in general but provides an error in LayerPreview sometimes when I move map from one place to another. And missing objects in the resulted WMS.

But what type of geometry column?

Sorry, not sure which exactly you meant. "geom" attribute in the layer itself has type Geometry. And the same stated on GeoServer. In the View "geometry_columns" there is attribute "f_geometry_column" (name) and attribute "type" (character varying). Is it what you meant?

Usually you would specify an actual geometry type such as polygon or line string. Can you see what type the missing geometries are?

I apologies, do you refer to the geom attribute in the database table, which has type "geometry" in my case? In general, problematic layer has cadastral polygons.

I would change the type to polygon then, this will probably tell you which geometries are broken
